# How to see the cookies in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, http, cookies

I am using Firefox 4 on a MacBook Pro. I want to see the cookies set by a specific site I am browsing (cookie name and cookie values). I am wondering whether there are any existing tools to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preferences, tabsheet Privacy, with "Use custom settings for history", button Show Cookies. And then just click any cookie you'd like to see:

[image: Firefox privacy settings]
[image: Firefox Cookies overview]

Or, while browsing, regardless whether using custom settings or not: hit Command-I for the Page Info, tabsheet Security, button View Cookies:

[image: Firefox Page Info]

(While developing, [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/) might be more useful.)

Comment: Hi Arjan, in tabsheet Privacy, there is no button called Show Cookies.

Comment: [There is](http://i.imgur.com/KCaRT.png) in my Firefox 4.0.1 on Snow Leopard, @George. Ah, it needs "Use custom settings for history". I guess Command-I is easier then?

Comment: Still works on Firefox 26.